# Combine two tables with different columns and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

How can I combine two tables with different data and set value for `CompanyC` to all data in Table 2 even there is no relationship of `CompanyC` on Table2.

```
  Table 1:                                 Table 2:

company     jobs                          company     jobs     emp_name
-----------------------------------      ---------------------------------
CompanyA     IT                           CompanyA     IT        John
CompanyB     Business                     CompanyB     Business  Mike
CompanyC     Engineer
```

And the Result Table would be like:

```
company     jobs            emp_name           
------------------------------------------    
CompanyA     IT                John     
CompanyC     Engineer          John  
CompanyB     Business          Mike      
CompanyC     Engineer          Mike
```

I already tried this and it is working but the problem is since CompanyC has no data on Table 2. The result will be null.

```
select coalesce(t1.company, t2.company)
       t1.jobs, t2.emp_name
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name = t1.name;
```

Comment: Where is the relationship between Company C and Mike & John coming from? They work for Company B and A respectively

Comment: yes there is no relationship. between Company C and John, Mike. But on my Result Table I want to set CompanyC for John and Mike.

Comment: So, again, where is that relationship coming from? "I want" doesn't explain the logic behind it.

Comment: There is no relationship of CompanyC on Table2 but I want to set CompanyC to all datas on my result table.

Comment: I added a new data on Table 2. Which is Company D that has no connection to Table 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an `INNER` join of the tables and use `NOT EXISTS` in the `ON` clause like this:

```
SELECT t1.company, t1.jobs, t2.emp_name
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.company = t1.company
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE company = t1.company)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=881b3635d8764bd93444fe270a8241c4).
Results:

```
> company  | jobs     | emp_name
> :------- | :------- | :-------
> CompanyA | IT       | John    
> CompanyC | Engineer | John    
> CompanyB | Business | Mike    
> CompanyC | Engineer | Mike
```

Comment: @forpas if the table2 has data that did not exist on table 1 is it still possible to join?

Comment: @Jboy my query answers you original question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can post a new question and not change the original requirement invalidating the answers that you already received.

Comment: Ok @forpas i will post new question thank you.

Comment: @forpas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230303/ms-sql-combine-2-tables-with-different-data-on-each

Comment: @Dale K I already accepted this answer and mark it up. Since I am now developing on next step that is why I created new question.