# Combine 2 Tables with different data on each

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

How can I combine two tables with different data and set value for `CompanyC` to all data in Table 2 and `CompanyD` has no relationship on Table 1. I want the `Company C` to set all data on Table 2.

```
   T1:                                 T2:

company     jobs                        emp_id  company     jobs     emp_name
-----------------------------------      -------------------------------------
CompanyA     IT                          1      CompanyA     IT        John
CompanyB     Business                    2      CompanyB     Business  Mike
CompanyC     Engineer                    3      CompanyD     Nurse     Mitch
```

And the result table would be like:

```
emp_id     company      jobs            emp_name           
----------------------------------------------     
1          CompanyA     IT                John     
1          CompanyC     Engineer          John  
2          CompanyB     Business          Mike      
2          CompanyC     Engineer          Mike
3          CompanyD     Nurse             Mitch
3          CompanyC     Engineer          Mitch
```

This is what I've tried

```
 SELECT  t2.emp_id, coalesce(t1.company_name, t2.company_name) AS company_name, 
    coalesce(t1.jobs, t2.jobs) AS jobs, 
    t2.emp_name, 
FROM Table1 t1  
    FULL OUTER JOIN      
    Table2 t2 ON t2.company = t1.company AND t2.jobs = t1.jobs
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two tables with different columns and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214666/combine-two-tables-with-different-columns-and-data)

Comment: That question is already solved. I posted this new question since I added some data on T2 which has no relation on T1. I don't want to edit the previous question since it is already solved

Comment: You still did not explain the logic required.

Comment: @Squirrel I am  using full outer join but since Company C and Company D has no relationship on each other it will become null

Comment: @DaleK

`SELECT  t2.emp_id, coalesce(t1.company_name, t2.company_name) AS company_name, coalesce(t1.jobs, t2.jobs) AS jobs, t2.emp_name,
FROM Table1 t1
 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Table2 t2
ON t2.company = t1.company AND t2.jobs = t1.jobs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an `INNER JOIN` of the tables for the companies that exist in `Table1` and then `UNION ALL` for the companies of `Table2` that do not exist in `Table1`:

```
SELECT t2.emp_id, t1.company, t1.jobs, t2.emp_name
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.company = t1.company
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE company = t1.company)
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE company = t2.company)
```

It is not clear in your question if you the 2 tables must be linked only on `company` or on `jobs` also, in which case you should use this query:

```
SELECT t2.emp_id, t1.company, t1.jobs, t2.emp_name
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.company = t1.company  AND t2.jobs = t1.jobs
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE company = t1.company AND jobs = t1.jobs)
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE company = t2.company AND jobs = t2.jobs)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c0666fec4f32c1107c660e2fceaad19).
Results:

```
emp_id | company  | jobs     | emp_name
-----: | :------- | :------- | :-------
     1 | CompanyA | IT       | John    
     1 | CompanyC | Engineer | John    
     2 | CompanyB | Business | Mike    
     2 | CompanyC | Engineer | Mike    
     3 | CompanyC | Engineer | Mitch   
     3 | CompanyD | Nurse    | Mitch
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked on mine but I have one last question in continuation of this  to complete. I will post a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248274/how-to-combine-multiple-tables-with-different-columns#65248274 this is my last problem

Answer (score 3):

Simplest logic would be to divide it in small logics and then use `union` as follows:

```
Select t2.*
  From t1 join t2 on t1.company = t2.comapny and t1.jobs = t2.jobs
Union
Select t1.company, T2.jobs, T2.emp_name
  From t1 cross join t2
Where not exists (select 1 from t2 t22
                   Where t1.company = t22.comapny and t1.jobs = t22.jobs)
Union 
Select t2.* 
  From t2 where not exists ( select 1 from t1 
                              where t1.company = t2.comapny and t1.jobs = t2.jobs)
```

Comment: This only shows

`company  jobs  emp_name`
`--------------------------------------------------`
`                                              `
`CompanyA  IT  John`
`CompanyB  Business  John`
`CompanyZ  Nurse  John`

Comment: @Jboy I have updated the answer. Please check now